# Trying to retrieve list of all spreadsheets in Google Docs

Tags: java, eclipse, google-sheets-api

I am new to use Google Spreadsheet APIs.

I want to retrieve the list of all the spreadsheets for the currently authenticated user using JAVA.

What should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The google data api developer guide documentation explains with examples.

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#ListingSpreadsheets

Check the java tab.

```
URL metafeedUrl = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
for (int i = 0; i < spreadsheets.size(); i++) {
  SpreadsheetEntry entry = spreadsheets.get(i);
  System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

service is an authenticated SpreadsheetService object

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService();  
service.setAuthSubToken(sessionAuthToken);
```

Comment: how do i create service object here?

Comment: this is V3 and will be removed in September 2020